# Fetch and Store ISBN Information from Amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm looking to allow users to submit an ISBN number and have a script search a Amazon web service and return the book name, author, description, and cover. Would anyone know what service or API would let me accomplish this, and if possible what script would I use to fetch the information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search by ISBN using the **Product Advertising API**.

The exact method is documenter here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html

In order to use the API you have to sign up with the Amazon stores.